# Page out of bound in Ghostscript

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, jpeg, ghostscript

I'm using GhostScript to convert each of the PDF page to JPEG. But My Problem is that if the PDF is large(say above 300 pages), it is unable to convert and displaying the message: "This page can't be displayed" or "Page out of bound". DO you face similar issue?

Thanks Guys. I resolved the Problem. Actually, it is the issue of the asp.net file upload control, which is not accepting the file size greater than 4 MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Ghostscript are you using ? The test suite which is executed on every commit includes the PLRM which is > 1000 pages and works without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use multi-thread mode for rasterization? `-dNumRenderingThreads=8` I have the same problem when tried to render large reports. It looks like a resource lock. As a workaround I have used the 1 thread.